# Unknown bounded continuous distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Has the continuous distribution with the following probability density function in $(0,1)$ a name?

$f(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1}{\alpha^\beta\Gamma(\beta)}(-\log x)^{\beta-1}x^{\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}}$

with $\alpha,\beta>0$

Comment: OK, it should be the log-gamma distribution... see for example inside this survey: [click here](http://threeplusone.com/gud)